# Asking a question that helps answer a different question

Tags: discussion

I want to answer a question on SO, and I've thought of a really good way to solve it.

But I am unsure exactly how to code one particular part, so  I ask a question on SO about that part.  Now I could take the answer I received from my question and create a great answer to the first question, but am afraid this might be frowned-upon in the SO world.

Is it considered bad practice to ask a question that will in-turn help me answer a different question?

Comment: If the new question is valid on its own, and distinct from the original, that seems fine.

Comment: It depends. Specifically, it depends on how much of the answer to the original question was provided by the one answering your question. Might be a good idea to link to that question for background, explanation, praise and attribution. Answering questions on SO sure might prompt you to create a few great questions.

Comment: @Deduplicator - That's exactly the case. Except I made no reference to the other question in mine, and made it a general question.  The question I wanted to answer is what prompted my question.  But now I wonder if it's a good idea to go answer the question with the answer I received from someone else.

Comment: It is fine to **build** an answer from another answer but you have to explicitly acknowledge that this is the case. Mention the name of the author of the other answer and provide a link. If you include something literally from that answer indicate it.